# How do you call files without drive path

Tags: vb.net

I don't know how to explain this right but I would like to ask you guys how do you call all the files in a folder without the "C:\" directory so wherever I move my project in another computer I don't have to edit the path directory in my project is that even possible? I'm using visual basic 2008.

Comment: Are you talking about data files used by your application? (images, xml or other specific data required by the app)

Comment: what files or directory uses your application ?

Comment: it shouldn't really cause a problem... I mean, I use projects on my laptop, my main desktop computer and they all open fine - unless you meddle with the inner workings of the files. What problems are you exactly having here? Give a scenario you are running into. your question is not fully clear

Comment: I mean like audio files and image files

Comment: My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\F.wav") here an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` , this code will return the directory where the current application is located, lets say you want to get all the directories in the folder where the application is located, then you will get something like this.

```
    Dim currentpath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory 'Get the directory where the application is located.
    Dim Directories() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(currentpath) 'get all the directories what are in the current location of the application
    '
    Console.WriteLine("This application is located at:: {0}", currentpath)
    '
    If Directories.Length = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("There aren't any folders found in the location of the application.")
    Else
        '
        Console.WriteLine("The follow folder(s) are found.")
        '
        For Each folder In Directory.GetDirectories(currentpath)
            Console.WriteLine(folder)
        Next
        '
    End If
    '
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Output:

```
This application is located at :: C:Users\Kona\Desktop\
The follow folder(s) are found.
C:\Users\Kona\Desktop\C#
C:\Users\Kona\Desktop\VB
C:\Users\Kona\Desktop\Haskell
C:\Users\Kona\Desktop\Java
```

Comment: It says "Directory" is not declared

Comment: You need to add "Imports System.IO" to the top of the document.

Comment: This example is used for a console application, of your post i assume that you're using a windows apllication, if this is the case you should replace "Console.Writeline" with for example a messagebox. If this is not the case (so you're using a console application), then there aren't any folders in the location where the application is located. the output should be in that case "There arent any folders found. "

Comment: Hey man one more question how do i add the currentpath i did it like this but didnt work My.Computer.Audio.Play(currentpath + "Medium.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

Comment: The code : My.Computer.Audio.Play(currentpath + "Medium.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete) will be converted to (in my case)::  C:Users\Kona\Desktop\Medium.wav , however VB.NET doesn't use the "+" operator to add two strings together but the "&" operator, for the second part, if your file called "Medium.wav" isn't in the same folder the as application is it won't work (with the example you provided)

Comment: Ok i got it now thank you! I did this My.Computer.Audio.Play(folder & "\A.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just use the:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

variable.
(use ..\ to go up a directory...)